# What does /dev/sda3: clean mean on boot?

Tags: 16.04

After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, on boot it shows

```
/dev/sda3: clean, 291272/4292608 files, 480345/18174432 blocks
```

which makes Ubuntu take some time to load

Comment: no that's not an error and doesn't need a solution. If your boot is slow, there is another reason for it

Answer (score 3):

This is the output of a filesystem check at boot for the `/dev/sda3` partition. `fsck` (actually probably `e2fsck` if it's an ext4 filesystem, which is the default for modern Ubuntu installations) is the program which carries out the checks. This is set to happen after a configurable number of reboots, or after a certain time period. It can also be triggered if you had to switch your computer off without properly shutting down, such as if you had to shut down by holding the power button in.

The piece of information that is most relevant is the word 'clean', which indicates that everything's in working order. So there's nothing to worry about.

The files and blocks part of the output show how many of the available files and blocks are in use. The files part actually applies to inodes, which are the underlying filesystem location for a file. So you're using 291272 out of the 4292608 available files spaces, and 480345 of the available 18174432 blocks on that partition.

The filesystem check will slow down your boot time, but shouldn't happen on every boot. There's also normally an option to press <kbd>C</kbd> to quit the check.

Comment: Seems this happens on every boot now - I see that message every time (and others say the same) and my boot time is <8 seconds.

Comment: If it's happening on every boot, there may be a problem with the disk, or perhaps the settings aren't quite right. Does the file `/forcefsck` exist on your system?

Comment: the file doesn't exist. I do think this is normal in 16.04 from talking to others...

Comment: So it is, how annoying. It can be disabled, but probably isn't wise to never check! I'm going to mark this question as a dupe.

Answer (score -2):

The boot times of the newer distros only seem to be increasing.
[Graph of boot time increase.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnyb5.png)

The information it shows is usually something you'd see in ubuntu server. Its just displaying what its currently doing while your system is loading. The slower boot times seems to be the new trend with the newer releases :D